# Consolidate multiple object classes into generic class

Tags: c#, class, generics

I am maintaining an existing C# application that implements three objects as classes that are identical except for name.

```
public class Role1
{
     public string lala {get;set;}
     public string abab {get;set;}
     public string cxcx {get;set;}
     public Role1(string lala, string abab, string cxcx)
     {
     }
     public List<Role1> GetMembers()
     {
         return dataaccesslayer.GetRole1Members();
     }
}

public class Role2
{
     public string lala {get;set;}
     public string abab {get;set;}
     public string cxcx {get;set;}
     public Role2(string lala, string abab, string cxcx)
     {
     }
     public List<Role2> GetMembers()
     {
         return dataaccesslayer.GetRole2Members();
     }
}

public class Role3
{
     public string lala {get;set;}
     public string abab {get;set;}
     public string cxcx {get;set;}
     public Role3(string lala, string abab, string cxcx)
     {
     }
     public List<Role3> GetMembers()
     {
         return dataaccesslayer.GetRole3Members();
     }
}
```

Within the data access layer, the members are pulled from a SharePoint list filtered by the string value of the Role Name. example "Role1"

I tried to create a generic class implementation like this:

```
 public class Role
 {
     public string lala {get;set;}
     public string abab {get;set;}
     public string cxcx {get;set;}
     public RoleType RoleType {get;set;}

     public Role(RoleType roletype, string lala, string abab, string cxcx)
     {
     }
     public static List<T> GetMembers<T>(ref T roletype,... )
     {
         return dataaccesslayer.GetRoleMembers<T>(roletype,...);
     }

 }
```

In the data layer class:

```
public List<T> GetMembers<T>(ref T roletype,...)
{
    ....
    return....
}
```

But the compiler throws GetMembers has some invalid arguments....

What have I missed?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is the argument by `ref` and what is the full call and implementation look like?

Comment: Role does not have a T

Comment: The ref was from the example I found on the MS web site. I tried with and without. @paparazzo T is just a place holder for the type which is identified by the roletype in the call. At least that's the way I understand it from the MS documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic implementation makes more sense if you split the classes into two parts - a definition of the role and something that provides members of the role. Perhaps something like this:

```
public class Role
{
    public string lala { get; set; }
    public string abab { get; set; }
    public string cxcx { get; set; }
}

// Very likely this could just be an interface. There's not much use for
// an abstract class that doesn't implement anything. It effectively *is* 
// an interface.
public abstract class RoleMembersProvider<TRole> where TRole : Role
{
    public abstract List<TRole> GetMembers();
}

public class Role1MemberProvider : RoleMemberProvider<Role1>
{
    public override List<Role1> GetMembers()
    {
        return dataaccesslayer.GetRole1Members();
    }
}
```

But this direct answer to the question leads to a few other questions.

Do all of the roles actually have the same properties? If so, do they even need to be separate classes? Could you just have the one `Role` class? If you have three classes (`Role1`, `Role2`, `Role3`) and they're all the same, then the only thing distinguishing them is their type, which in turn means that you're using the type as data. That could lead to some weird generic behavior where you're checking the type of an object like it's a property so you can tell what do with it.

If they're not separate classes, then do you need multiple classes to get the members of the roles, or could you just just have this:

```
public class RoleMembersProvider
{
    public List<Role> GetRoleMembers(string roleName)
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. All classes are identical except the type. I did not write the original code so am trying to simplify for a couple reasons, most importantly because adding an additional role currently takes copying one of the existing classes and changing the type to the new role which would be mitigated if there were only one class. I believe I need to keep them as types (objects) because there are so many places that reference them as types.

Comment: Scott, if I understand your suggestions it seems that in either case - and possibly in any scenario - adding a new role would require a code change even though it would be minimal such as adding a new case in the select block for the new role. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: Scott, one more thing: you mention using the type as data. I'm not sure if that's what is happening. This scenario is for a workflow application and the various roles are only to decide who takes the next step in the approval process. Say, if Joe smith is a member of Role1 and the WF calls for approval by a Role1 member, Joe Smith would be included for that approval. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi, I don't think that "type as data" is happening in the code you've shown. It's just a possibility down the road if you have three classes which have exactly the same properties. If you want to know what type of role it is (1, 2, 3) you would have to check the type. An alternative would be just having one class with those properties, and adding another property to distinguish what type of role it is.

Answer (score 1):

If they are identical then why not an abstract class?

```
public abstract class Role
{
    public string lala { get; set; }
    public string abab { get; set; }
    public string cxcx { get; set; }
    public Role(string lala, string abab, string cxcx)
    {
    }
    public abstract List<Role> GetMembers();
}
```

Comment: Can an abstract class inherit from a base class?